# How to create objects in foundry?

Tags: object, palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api, objectset

Recently started working on palantir's foundry. The documentation is poor, unable to figure out how to create objects at the first place.

I was able to create an object type, however poorly configured, how do I use the objects from it in the object viewer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create an object type in the [Ontology Manager](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/ontology-manager/overview/index.html) app. Sounds like you've done this. Great!
2. [Pick a backing dataset for that object type](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-link-types/create-object-type/index.html#create-a-new-object-type-and-add-a-backing-datasource) in the Ontology Manager app. Each row in this dataset should have a unique value for its primary key column, and each row should correspond to a single object.
3. When the dataset has been indexed into the ontology -- which will start automatically when you save your object type with a backing dataset -- you'll be able to use the [Object Explorer](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-explorer/overview/index.html) app to view each object. The [default view for an object](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-views/overview/index.html) type in Object Explorer is pretty spartan -- just some properties and any links to other objects -- but you can configure it to include other widgets and data.

If you don't have a backing dataset, you can use an empty dataset with just a schema (header row, essentially) and create an [Action](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/action-types/overview/index.html) to create objects. Then you can call that action via [its API endpoint](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/api/ontology-resources/actions/apply-action/index.html) or use it in an Object View, a [Workshop app](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/workshop/actions-use/index.html), etc. to create individual objects.